# nginx password protect a password protected url

Tags: nginx

I am trying to reverse proxy to my home camera. The camera is password protected. also I add a password protected config in nginx, but it keep redirecting between two password request pages even I got both passwords correct.

auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;